# Performance on Degenerated Dimension for drillthrough Action and Processing

Tags: sql, performance, ssas, data-warehouse, olap

There is a lot of information that doesn't fit as Measures and also not have the necessary dimensionality so I decided to integrate this data in the FactTable for a later drillthrough Action (informations like Document Number, Document Line, etc.). So I use the FactTable as a fact dimension (or degenerate dimension as Kimball calls it). The Fact dimension was related after creation with the Measure Group as in the picture below:

[image: Fact Dimension]

The FactTable/Fact dimension has 140.000.000 rows so I decide to use the ROLAP as storage mode trying to avoid the MOLAP processing but now the performance issues are moved in the drillthrough action. All others Dimensions are in MOLAP.
Analysis is istalled on 64x-Server with 98GB RAM and the `Memory\TotalMemoryLimit` was set to 70% .

I also activate a Profiler when the drillthrough action (over the degenerate dimension in rolap) was performed so I get the SQL-Query. Lots of aggregation and group by - no wondering.

How can I deal with performace in this case so that the drillthrough Action and the processing of degenerate dimension will perform in a timely fashion manner?

**UPDATE 13.04**

I attached below the execution plan for the query received in Profiler:
[image]

```
SELECT  
SUM ( [dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[Amount] ) AS Amount, 
SUM ( [dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[SharedAmount] ) AS SharedAmount,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[Pk_id] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentNo] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentLine] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentHeader] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentType] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[Reference] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentDate] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[EntryDate] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[FiscalPeriod] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[StornoDocNo] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentCurrency] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[CustomerNumber] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[EnteredBy] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[PartnerSegment] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[PartnerBusinessArea] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ItemText] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Date] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_CostCategory] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_CostCenter] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Currency] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Branch] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Customer] ,
[dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Scenario] ,
[dbo_DimCostCategory_3].[AccountNo] ,
[dbo_DimCostCategory_3].[AccountNameDEU] ,
[dbo_DimCostCategory_3].[AccountNameEng] ,
[dbo_DimCostCategory_3].[AccountType] ,
[dbo_DimCostCategory_3].[AccountSetSAP] ,
[dbo_DimCostCenter_4].[CostCenterNo] ,
[dbo_DimCostCenter_4].[CostCenterName] ,
[dbo_DimCostCenter_4].[CostCenterAliasDEU] ,
[dbo_DimCostCenter_4].[CostCenterAliasENG] ,
[dbo_DimCurrency_5].[CurrencyCode] ,
[dbo_DimCurrency_5].[CurrencyENG] ,
[dbo_DimBranchShare_6].[Branch No] ,
[dbo_DimBranchShare_6].[Branch Name DE] ,
[dbo_DimBranchShare_6].[Branch Name TM1] ,
[dbo_DimBranchShare_6].[Branch Name ENG] ,
[dbo_DimBranchShare_6].[BranchId] ,
[dbo_DimBranchShare_6].[SharePercentage] ,
[dbo_DimBranchShare_6].[Branch Name ASL] ,
[dbo_DimBranchShare_6].[Country] ,
[dbo_DimBranchShare_6].[Currency] ,
[dbo_DimBranchShare_6].[IsSAP] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Customer No] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Customer Name1] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Short Name] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Street] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Country] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Postal Code] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Telefon No] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Fax TeletexNo] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Attending BST] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Key Industry Sector] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Booking No] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Status Inactiv] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Company Key] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Direct Mailing Forwarder] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Direct Mailing BKeeping] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Direct Mailing Sales] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Direct Mailing Magazines] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Customer Name2] ,
[dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Customer Name3] ,
[dbo_DimScenario_8].[ScenarioTypeENG] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Quarter] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Jan-Feb] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Jan-Mrz] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Jan-Apr] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Jan-Mai] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Jan-Jun] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Jan-Jul] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Jan-Aug] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Jan-Sep] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Jan-Okt] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Jan-Nov] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Jan-Dez] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[MonthName] ,
[dbo_DimDate_2].[Semester]
FROM (
      SELECT 
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[Pk_id],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Date],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Scenario],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Branch],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_CostCategory],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_CostCenter],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Customer],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Currency],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentNo],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentLine],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentHeader],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentType],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[Reference],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentDate],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[EntryDate],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[FiscalPeriod],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[StornoDocNo],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[DocumentCurrency],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[CustomerNumber],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[EnteredBy],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[PartnerSegment],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[PartnerBusinessArea],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[ItemText],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[Amount],
             [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details].[SharedAmount]
        FROM [dbo].[FactCdbSAP_Details]
        WHERE 
            id_date >201509
            )  AS [dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details], 
                [dbo].[DimCostCategory] AS [dbo_DimCostCategory_3],
                [dbo].[DimCostCenter] AS [dbo_DimCostCenter_4],
                [dbo].[DimCurrency] AS [dbo_DimCurrency_5],
                [dbo].[DimBranchShare] AS [dbo_DimBranchShare_6],
                [dbo].[DimCustomers] AS [dbo_DimCustomers_7],
                [dbo].[DimScenario] AS [dbo_DimScenario_8],
                [dbo].[DimDate] AS [dbo_DimDate_2]

WHERE 

            [dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Date] = [dbo_DimDate_2].[ID_Date]
            AND     
            [dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_CostCategory]  = [dbo_DimCostCategory_3].[PK_Cost]
            AND     
            [dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_CostCenter] = [dbo_DimCostCenter_4].[Pk_CostCenter]
            AND     
            [dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Currency] = [dbo_DimCurrency_5].[Pk_Currency]
            AND     
            [dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Branch] =  [dbo_DimBranchShare_6].[PK_ShareBranch]
            AND     
            [dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Customer] = [dbo_DimCustomers_7].[Pk_Customer]
            AND     
            [dbo_FactCdbSAP_Details].[ID_Scenario] = [dbo_DimScenario_8].[Pk_Scenario]
            AND     
            [dbo_DimCurrency_5].[CurrencyDEU] = 'Lokale Währung'
            AND     
            [dbo_DimScenario_8].[ScenarioTypeDEU] = 'Ist'       
            AND     
            [dbo_DimDate_2].[Year] = 2016   
            AND     
            [dbo_DimDate_2].[Month] = 2
group by 
....
```

Comment: What's the SQL query it runs during drillthrough? Are you able to manually edit the SQL query to make it run fast? Please provide the original and optimized SQL. I doubt we will be able to help but it's possible.

Comment: @GregGalloway I have attached the execution plan and the query that has been executed during drillthrough action (in a pivot table). I cannot modify the query. Would be an indexing plan a good idea? I know that indexes are not recommended in a datawarehouse (it will slow down other transactions that are outside of drillthrough)

Comment: what version of SQL and edition? If SQL 2014 and Enterprise edition then switching the fact table to a clustered columnstore should help a lot.

Comment: are you able to make the query fast with some edits? For example is it fast if you remove the group bys? My guess is no given that the table scan is 85% of the cost

Comment: @GregGalloway we are talking about SQL Server 2012 wich only supports non-clustered columnstore indexes. I already have a non-clustered columnstore index on the fact table. This query is running in the background when the user connect to SSAS cube from excel, build a pivot table report (rows, columns, filters) and at the end doubleclick an Amount to see what documents are behind this. When the user doubleclicks the Amount cell, SSAS will run this query and attempt to bring the results in another Excel Sheet.

Comment: understood. If I read the query plan screenshot right it isn't using the columnstore to answer this query. I know you can't customize the SQL generated by the drillthrough but if you hand write the SQL are you able to make it run fast? Does removing the group bys help? Or is this going to be slow no matter what we do?

Comment: have you attempted to make the dimension MOLAP? I wonder if doing a MOLAP dimension loaded as ProcessAdd would perform well both for drillthrough and processing. http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2007/4/20/processadd-on-large-dimensions

Comment: @GregGalloway I saved the dimension in Molap Mode and used Processing Data with AttributeHierarchyOptimizedState=FullyOptimized for all atributes. I also set AttributeHierarchyOrdered=false for the key and I saved 4 min... I will also try to load as ProcessAdd and I will comeback with updates

Comment: @GregGalloway the following solution was implemented: 1. I created a delta table Today-Yesterday to find out what data are ok for ProcessAdd. 2.I created an SSIS Package with a Dataflow Task with the delta table as OLEDB Source and Dimension Processing Task as Destination (this means the ProcessAdd direct in the MOLAP Dimension ). 3.Processing the affected Cube Partition also with ProcessAdd option.

Comment: @GregGalloway Conclusion: The performance in cube and the drillthrough action is working good because of the aggregations defined in cube and the storage mode MOLAP .The processing of data takes 35 min now because of the ProcessAdd Dimension and Partition. This solution is working only when you don't need to track updates or deletes of data in the past.

Comment: excellent. Glad it is working well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109258/discussion-between-pirvu-georgian-and-greggalloway).

Comment: @GregGalloway could you please compose your idea of trying to use ProcessAdd in MOLAP with your blog as an Answer so I can mark it?

Comment: well you did most of the work here. So I think you should answer the question personally. Glad I could help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to receive a good performance both for drillthrough action and processing the following solution was found and implemented:

- I changed the storage mode of the degenerate dimension in MOLAP
- `AttributeHierarchyOptimizedState=FullyOptimized` for all atributes of the degenerate dimension
- `AttributeHierarchyOrdered=false` for the primary key of the degenerate dimension
- I implemented the Process Add. A Delta Table Today-Yesterday was created to find out data that are suitable for ProcessAdd (in this scenario old data won't change)
- An SSIS Package was created with a DataFlowTask. Inside the DataFlowTask,  delta table was set as OLEDB Source and Dimension Processing Task as Destination (this means Incremental Adds direct in the MOLAP Dimension ). The picture below shows that: 
  [image: Incremental Add in Dimension]
- In the end will be processed only the  affected Cube Partition also with ProcessAdd option.
  [image: ProcessAdd Partition]

Many thanks to **Greg Galloway** for describing ProcessAdd ond large dimension on this post http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2007/4/20/processadd-on-large-dimensions